# Where is the error in InitializeGrid? It's returning wrong indices

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I'm trying to code a Rectangle with multiple triangle strips joined together. according to:
http://www.corehtml5.com/trianglestripfundamentals.php

You need to take care of the triangles wrapping around when you have more than one row. However using the suggested algorithm in my code example I'm getting incorrect indice results.

Here is my example, with outputs.

I've tried copy/pasting the suggested algorithm but it doesn't seem to be returning correct results.

```
// Create the Index Points for the buffer array.
var rows=2;
var cols=3;
var grid = rows*cols;
var offset;
var pos = [];
var index = 0;
var mpOffset = 1;
for (var row = 0; row <= rows; ++row)
{
  offsetY = row * (mpOffset / rows);
  for (var col = 0; col <= cols; ++col)
  {
    offsetX = col * (mpOffset / cols);

    pos[index+0] = (offsetX);
    pos[index+1] = (offsetY);
    index+=2;
  }
}
log.info("pos="+JSON.stringify(pos)); //  <-- Correct working good.
log.info("pos.length="+pos.length);

function initializeGrid(cols,rows)
{
    var trianglestrip = [];
    var RCvertices=2*cols*(rows-1);
    var TSvertices=2*cols*(rows-1)+2*(rows-2);
    var numVertices=TSvertices;
    var j=0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= RCvertices; i += 2)
    {
        trianglestrip[ j ] = (1 +i)/2;
        trianglestrip[ j +1 ] = (cols*2 + i + 1) / 2;
        if( trianglestrip[ j +1 ] % cols == 0) 
        {
            if( trianglestrip[ j +1 ] != cols && trianglestrip[ j +1 ] != cols*rows )
            {
                trianglestrip[ j +2 ] = trianglestrip[ j +1 ];
                trianglestrip[ j +3 ] = (1 + i + 2) / 2;
                j += 2; 
            }
        }
        j += 2;
    }
    return trianglestrip;
}

var triStrip = initializeGrid(cols,rows);
log.info("triStrip="+JSON.stringify(triStrip)); // <-- Bad Not working.
log.info("triStrip.length="+triStrip.length);

// Generating the actual Point strip.
var actualStrip = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < triStrip.length; ++i)
{
    actualStrip.push(pos[(triStrip[i]-1)*2+0]);
    actualStrip.push(pos[(triStrip[i]-1)*2+1]);
}
log.info("actualStrip="+JSON.stringify(actualStrip));
log.info("actualStrip.length="+actualStrip.length);
```

Indices should be:
1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 8, 5, 5, 9, 6, 10, 7, 11, 8, 12

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-creating the function to calculate the triangle strip indices. Have not fully tested it but it can re-create the 3x2 grid in the example from the website.

Here is the code:

```
// This calculates the triangle points in a rectangular triangle strip.
// Used for 3D Webgl texture mapping.
// Copyright Joshua Langley 2019.
var rows=2;
var cols=3;
var grid = rows*cols;
var offset;
var pos = [];
var index = 0;
var mpOffset = 1;
var offsetX, offsetY;
for (var row = 0; row <= rows; ++row)
{
  offsetY = row * (mpOffset / rows);
  for (var col = 0; col <= cols; ++col)
  {
    offsetX = col * (mpOffset / cols);

    pos[index+0] = (offsetX);
    pos[index+1] = (offsetY);
    index+=2;
  }
}
log.info("pos="+JSON.stringify(pos));
log.info("pos.length="+pos.length);

var rows=rows+1,cols=cols+1; // Important this counting Points not Squares.
var grid = rows*cols;
var offset;
var indices = [];
var indice = 0;
var offset;
var doublePoints = false;
var tPoint, bPoint;
for (var row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
{ 
  for (var col = 0; col < (cols-1); ++col)
  {
      offset = row * rows + col;
      tPoint = offset+1;
      bPoint = offset+cols+1;

      if (bPoint > grid)
          continue;

      indices.push(tPoint);           
      indices.push(bPoint);
      if (offset > 0 && (bPoint+1) < grid && (offset+1) % cols == 0)
      {
          indices.push(bPoint);
          indices.push(tPoint+1);
      }                   
  }
}
log.info("indices="+JSON.stringify(indices)); // Expected Result
log.info("indices.length="+indices.length);

var actualStrip = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < indices.length; ++i)
{
    actualStrip.push(pos[(indices[i]-1)*2+0]);
    actualStrip.push(pos[(indices[i]-1)*2+1]);
}
log.info("actualStrip="+JSON.stringify(actualStrip));
log.info("actualStrip.length="+actualStrip.length);
```